# Add addslashes and htmlentities on every request

Tags: php, xss, sql-injection

How do i put addslashes(htmlentities(...)) on each _POST?

```
if ( isset ( $_POST ) ):
     foreach ( $_POST as $name => $val ) :
           $_POST[$name] = addslashes(htmlentities($val));
     endforeach;
endif;
```

Will this works?

Comment: Doesn't mean its a good idea though.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself? In any case, if you find any need to do this then *you are doing something wrong*. There is a much better way to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Modifying your input values is a Bad Idea (tm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking this without trying? As far as I can see it should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this work?

It only works if no array's get passed like in `?name[]=tony&name[]=anthony`.

And why would you do that? If you do this for protection you should use these functions only when needed.

use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (or even better [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO)) instead of `addslashes()` to make sure no SQL Injection is possible. Example:

```
// using mysql_real_escape_string
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) .  "'";

// using PDO (recommended)
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?");
$statement->execute(array($name));
```

use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()` to prevent XSS. Example:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>" />
```